# Ударение в слове "поднял".

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Я поднЯл поддоны. Правильно ли я сегодня сказал?

Answer (score 2):

Допустимы и пОднял, и поднЯл. Более старшая норма - пОднял. Но уже у Аванесова в орфоэпическом словаре поднЯл дается как допустимый вариант. Правда, у Зарвы почему-то дается  только пОднял.